# NServiceBus Ninject could not find the NinjectObjectBuilder scope when using ToMethod

Tags: c#, ninject, nservicebus

I have a messaging context object defined to be unique per incoming message processing:

```
Bind<MessagingContext>().ToSelf().InUnitOfWorkScope();
```

Also I registered a custom interface to be resolved dynamically via Ninject ToMethod extension:

```
Bind<IBus>().ToMethod(c =>
            {
                var messagingContext = c.Kernel.Get<MessagingContext>();
                return new Bus(messagingContext);
            });
```

Currently while resolving MessagingContext object instance I'm getting an exception:

```
Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope.UnknownScopeException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Error activating MessagingContext
The scope NinjectObjectBuilder is not known in the current context.
No matching scopes are available, and the type is declared InNamedScope(NinjectObjectBuilder).
```

Is there any way to correctly resolve the object registered as InUnitOfWorkScope inside the ToMethod?

I'm using:

- NServiceBus 6.4.2
- NServiceBus.Ninject 6.0.1
- Ninject 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be a bug with child containers and named scoping.

As a work around in the meantime, you can change your MessagingContext registration to be:

```
Bind<MessagingContext>().ToSelf().DefinesNamedScope("NinjectObjectBuilder");
```

Which will at least let Ninject know that the MessagingContext type is intended to be used within the child container.

Comment: As a workaround I used GetContextPreservingResolutionRoot extension method on kernel object, but I don't know if that is the best way to go